# how do I get a function to take two arguments?

Tags: python, list, function, arguments, program-entry-point

new to python. so i have this function, and I don't know how to get it to take two arguments and return it in another list with their positions.
in the main program i want it to call x  to search for in the list, and print the meassage where it occurs. 
am i going about this the right way?
this what I came up with.
would really appreciate the help
thanks in advance.

```
def find_multiple():
    arg1 = input(" L: " )
    arg2 = input(" x: ")

    return L

def main():
    L = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4 ]
    x = int(input("Enter an element to search for in the list: "))
    if (len(L_indexes) == 0):
        print(x, " does not occur in L.")
        L =[]
        results = L    

print("enter an element to search for in the list: " )
if(len(L) == 0):
    print("element does not occur in the list")
else:
    print("the number of occurrences in L: ", x)

main()
```

Comment: Do you know how to get a function to take one argument?

Comment: It might be a good idea to go through the tutorial ... http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

**Edit: Based on what you posted this is what I think you are trying to do.**

```
def search(myBigFancyX, myBigFancyList):

    counter = 0
    for number in myBigFancyList:
        if number == myBigFancyX:
            counter += 1
    return counter

if __name__ == "__main__":

    l = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4 ]
    x = int(input("Enter an element to search for in the list: "))

    occurances = search(x, l)
    if occurances == 0:
        print("element does not occur in the list")
    else:
        print("the number of occurrences in L: ", occurances)
```

Comment: ahh yes thank you. i was unsure as to where the arguments went. I had thought as what you posted here at first, but then I had doubts. thanks, this was a big help.

Comment: `search` appears to be a long way of writing `myBigFancyList.count(myBigFancyX)`...

Comment: @JonClements yep, but I'm willing to bet his teacher is expecting him to use primitives and what naught.